# Cannot Connect Galaxy S7 to Windows 10 Laptop for USB Debugging

Tags: windows-10, android, adb

As the title says, I cannot get my Samsung Galaxy S7 to connect to my computer and be recognized by `adb devices` for USB debugging. I've been at this for a few days now with no luck.

**State of my device:**

- Developer Mode is on
- USB Debugging is on
- When I plug it in, no notification comes up about a USB connection but it starts charging

**Things I've tried with no avail:**

- Different USB cables
- My Mac mini, same problem, no connection
- Connecting and switching developer mode on and off
- Connecting and switching debugging on and off
- `adb connect <Device Address>:5555` but the device does not listen for tcp connections on port 5555 by default
- Installing Samsung drivers
- Updating USB device drivers (already up to date)

**Other information:**

- No device shows up in the device manager that would be the S7 (no portable devices)

I do not know what else I could possibly do...

Comment: connect with a powered USB hub.  underpowered USB ports are common connection problem.

Comment: @somebadhat Bought [this](https://smile.amazon.com/Sabrent-4-Port-Individual-Switches-HB-UM43/dp/B00JX1ZS5O) powered usb hub off of Amazon. Just tried it out and it still doesn't work.

Comment: that is not a powered hub.  [this](https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-Individual-Switches-Included-HB-UMP3/dp/B00TPMEOYM/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=powered+usb+hub&qid=1554913201&s=electronics&sr=1-3) is.